# What to do when class implementing IList<T> requires that I implement Count property?

Tags: c#

I have the following class:

```
public class GraphingResults : IList<GraphingResult>
{
    public List<GraphingResult> ToolkitResultList { get; set; }

    public GraphingResults()
    {
        this.ToolkitResultList = new List<GraphingResult>();
    }

    // bunch of other stuff
}
```

As this class implements `IList<GraphingResult>`, it requires that I implement the following property (among many others!)

```
public int Count
{
    get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}
```

I'm not sure exactly what to do... do I need to return the count of `this.ToolkitResultList`?

Comment: Why do you bother implementing `IList`?  Why not just expose your `List` as a property?  It's not as though `IList` prevents modification, so not sure what the point is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To throw a question back at you, why are you exposing a List publicly, as well as implemented IList?

The answer is that you should be doing one or the other. ie, Either expose the list publicly as you are doing, and dont implement IList, or dont expose the List, and insteads make your class the interface to that list:

```
public class GraphingResults : IList<GraphingResult>
{
    private List<GraphingResult> ToolkitResultList { get; set; }

    public GraphingResults()
    {
        this.ToolkitResultList = new List<GraphingResult>();
    }

    // bunch of other stuff

    public int Count
    {
        get { return this.ToolkitResultList.Count; }
    }

}
```

Comment: I still really don't see the value in implementing `IList` for the purposes of wrapping an existing `List`.  It's a lot of work/boilerplate -- what conceivable benefit could there be?

Comment: @Kirk - I agree totally, but as I dont know the OP's intent I cant say what might be some benefit. One possibility might be to make an observable list which raises events when items are added/removed from the underlying list.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if this class is really just a wrapper around `ToolkitResultList` then that would make the most sense to me.

Comment: It's not a wrapper since it's publicly exposed.

Answer (score 0):

Your class would act as a proxy for the internally used List, but if this is your indented design, you might change the base class to Collection:

```
public class GraphingResults : Collection<GraphingResult>
{
}
```

you find this class in the System.Collections.ObjectModel namespace. It does all the work four you and is especially for cases like your's.